# Unable to create android virtual device in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am unable to create an Android Virtual Device in Eclipse. I added all basic SDK packages but still couldn't add any virtual device. The OK button is still disabled as demonstrated below.

[image: unable to create avd]

What might I be overlooking here and how do I resolve my problems?

Comment: help you in what ? what problem you are facing ?

Comment: I want to add AVD but ok button still disable.

Comment: extend the screen, it will show you the error

Comment: This is full screen view while adding a New AVD.
please let me know which thing i missed.

Comment: full image : http://i.stack.imgur.com/dva4G.png

Comment: no, this is not a full screen, there is no overide option visible, extend from bottom

Comment: I solved this ...
when i extend screen the error message show  :)
the message was : "GPU Emulation and Snapshot cannot be used simultaneously"
Thank you for your help.

Comment: There may be  with same name emulator is already available there

Comment: doesn't what to be mean, but I think my hint solved it. by the way glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use both `Snapshot` and `Use Host GPU` togather, it's either one or the other.

If you installed Intel Atom boost then use `Use Host GPU`

Hope that's the problem ;)

**EDIT:** If you make the window larger (taller) you will be able to see an error message at the bottom.

Comment: yes , correct :)
i am accepting your answer ,
your hint solved my issue.
Thank you.